# Google Adsense on Iphone's browser display issues. '-webkit-text-size-adjust' for google adsense on iphone browser

Tags: iphone, css, webkit, adsense, mobile-browser

I am having display issues with google adsense on Iphone browers. Title becomes smaller; descrption becomes larger, etc.. Is there a way I can implement '-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;' to Google Adsense (this is placed on an iFrame)? Or are there other ways to get this resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution just added the lines below on my stylesheet.

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px){
   body{
      -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can target something that is in an iframe if its content is served from another domain.. It's just impossible.

You can read this older question for more info: [How to apply CSS to iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe)